# Automatically detect a newly added file in a folder and print it on default printer

Tags: python, excel, pdf, printing, ms-word

due to compatibility issues in printing documents from my WIN7 pc to my boss' printer(LX 300+) installed on a networked(local) PC running on win xp, I would like to create an application that will create a folder on that PC(winxp) and print every time a new file is added(word,excel,pdf) on that folder(like dropbox except it prints rather than upload).

I did my research and I already got the script of printing (word, excel, pdf) and also a script on creating a directory/folder. All I need now is:

- A python script that is attached(or maybe some other way) into the
  folder(I don't know how does it work with Dropbox) that will detect a
  newly added file in that folder and print it automatically on default
  printer with its default print settings.

I'm using Python 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

There is no cross-platform way to watch for new files, short of reading the directory over and over and seeing what's changed, which is a very bad idea.

The right way to watch for new files being added to a folder on Windows is the [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.* [Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains how it works, and gives sample code in C++.

To use these functions from Python, you will need [`pywin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). (You could use `ctypes` or some other lower-level technique instead, but there's no good reason to do so.) The docs are in a .chm file inside the package, or you can find a copy of them [at ActiveState](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML). The functions you want are in the [`win32api`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32api__FindFirstChangeNotification_meth.html) module.

If you google for `Python FindFirstChangeNotification`, you will probably find lots of sample code. But it's going to look something like this (incomplete and untested code just to get you started):

```
ffc = win32api.FindFirstChangeNotification(path, 0,
                                           win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME)
last_contents = set(os.listdir(path))
while True:
    win32event.WaitForSingleObject(ffc, win32con.INFINITE)
    contents = set(os.listdir(path))
    new_files = contents - last_contents
    for file in new_files:
        run_your_script_that_prints_a_file(file)
    last_contents = contents
    win32api.FindNextChangeNotification(ffc)
```

In real-life code, you'll probably want some better error handling, and you'll want to `FindCloseChangeNotification(ffc)` when you're done.

---

* There's also [`ReadDirectoryChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is easier to use from C, and more flexible, and doesn't require listing the directory manually each time there's a change… but it's actually more painful from Python, and there's less sample code out there for it.

Comment: I had to change `win32con.INFINITE` to `win32event.INFINITE`.